# Stop rotation of text in loader div

Tags: html, css

I found `loader` CSS trick, and I want to put text or image into loader without rotation.

```css
.loader {
  border: 5px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 5px solid #fff;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.loader > span {
  animation: no-spin .5s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes no-spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">
  <span>LOGO</span>
</div>
```

I tried `@keyframes no-spin` for reverse rotation, but didn't work.

Comment: use **transform: rotate(-360deg)** for anticlockwise rotation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to add `display:block` on the `<span>`. A transform on `display:inline` will not work (as specified in the [spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-1/#terminology)). In practice this boils down to using `display:block` or `display:inline-block`.

I've also modified the animation time of `.no-spin` to `1s`, to match your spin animation speed. 
This will give the *illusion* of not spinning, in actuality it's spinning with the same speed in the opposite direction.

```css
.loader {
  border: 5px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 5px solid #fff;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.loader > span {
  display: block;
  animation: no-spin 1s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes no-spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">
  <span>LOGO</span>
</div>
```

Comment: It work with `inline-block` too, but you missed to explain what more you did to make it work, since that change alone does not sovle the issue

Comment: @LGSon Fair comment, I've expanded the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `spin` on a pseudo element

```css
.loader {
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.loader::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  border: 5px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 5px solid #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">
  <span>LOGO</span>
</div>
```